# Use pynput to exit out of otherwise infinite loop

Tags: python, pynput

I am trying to use pynput to close out of an infinite loop.  Right now when the code is run and after shift and f2 are pressed it will print "running" infinitely.  I want this loop to stop printing as soon as I press the esc key.  Here is my code.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from pynput import keyboard
import time

typer = Controller()


COMBINATIONS = [
    {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.Key.f2}
]


current = set()


def execute():
    while current != keyboard.Key.esc:
        print("running")

def on_press(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.add(key)
        if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
            execute()
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        sys.exit
        return False


def on_release(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.remove(key)


with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Some of this code may be extraneous as I am still learning pynput and am building this off of a program I wrote yesterday.  I have tried returning false and using sys.exit within the on_press function and changing the infinite loop to only run while the current key is not esc.